# How to place a paragraph element under the page logo which is displayed as flex?

Tags: html, css

I want to have a navigation bar like this picture below but I'm facing a problem with flex items and my paragraph which will be like a description under my logo. Is there any way to make it look exactly the same as what is in the picture?

[image: picture]

```css
#container {
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
  background: #fff;
  height: 120px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

#container a {
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

#container h1 {
    margin-left: 20px;
}

#container ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: 10rem;
}

#container ul li a {
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* margin: 0 1px; */
  padding: 47px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#container ul li a:hover {
  background: #f4f4f4;
}

/* Showcase */
#showcase {
  background: url(../IMG/man.jpg) no-repeat center center/cover;
  height: 87.2vh;
}

#showcase-content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 700px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navbar">
    <div id="container">
      <a href="#home"><h1><span class="text-primary">lorem</span> ipsum</h1></a>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#mywork">My Work</a></li>
    </div>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <header id="showcase">
    <div id="showcase-content">
      <a href="#about" class="btn">Check out</a>
    </div>
  </header>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please have a read here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  Basically, you wanna post simplified code to demonstrate the issue you are having. A picture on here is not worth a thousand words

Comment: Just keep the logo and the p tag in a div tag and add some basic css

Comment: Your css is missing. Post a [mcve].

Comment: I would suggest wrapping both the logo and p tag in a div of sorts. Although it's difficult to help without any CSS.

Comment: You can create a 'pen': https://codepen.io/pen/ and we will be able to see where is the problem and try to help.

Comment: @Roman Unnecessary since the same functionality exists here and cane be added within the question itself via a snippet

Comment: thanks for your suggestion Roman, I'm looking forward to using it already

Comment: @j08691 You are right but IMHO the codepen seems handier.

Comment: @Roman Not if codepen ever goes away, is down, or blocked by a firewall

Comment: Mind that there is some wrong nesting in your code. Have a look at the `<div>` inside your `<ul>`.

Comment: @DanielSixl yikes! thank you for reminding me that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a nested column:

```css
#container {
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 0 20px;
    background: #fff;
    height: 120px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

#container a {
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

#container h1 {
    margin-left: 20px;
}

#container ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-right: 10rem;
}

#container ul li a {
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    /* margin: 0 1px; */
    padding: 47px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

#container ul li a:hover {
    background: #f4f4f4;
}

.flex-col {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navbar">
    <div id="container">
        <div class="flex-col">
            <a href="#home">
                <h1>Heading</h1>
            </a>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor.</p>
        </div>
        
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#mywork">My Work</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have two sub elements in your flexbox-header. Use another flexbox for your navigation.

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif !important;
  background: #111 url('https://i.picsum.photos/id/66/1600/1000.jpg') no-repeat center center scroll;
  background-size: cover;
}

.container {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 2rem 1rem;
}



header {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.navbar-horizontal {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

#branding {
  flex: 2;
}

#branding h1 a {
  font-size:  1.5rem;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 700;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

#navbar-main {
  flex: 3;
  margin-top: 2rem;
}

#navbar-main a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.section-heading {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  .container--flex {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
  }
  #navbar-main {
    margin: 0 0 0 2rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<header>
  <div class="container container--flex">
    <div id="branding">
      <h1><a href="#home">Lorem ip</a></h1>
      <p>Fascilis mauris sit amet masse </p>
    </div>
    <nav id="navbar-main" class="navbar-horizontal">
        <a href="#home">Home</a>
        <a href="#about">About</a>
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        <a href="#mywork">My Work</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>

<main>
  <div class="container">
    <section id="showcase">
      <h2 class="section-heading">Showcase</h2>
    </section>
  </div>
</main>
```